# don't know how to use tcsetpgrp()

Tags: c, operating-system

I am not sure how to use tcsetpgrp()  `int tcsetpgrp(int fildes, pid_t pgid_id);` , I want to set the foreground group pid to become the child's new group pid so that when I typed control-C, it will only kill my child process in my terminal, not the background terminal. (I think currently, the parent group pid is the same as the shell's foreground gpid)

```
    // we are in the child process
    // check the foreground process group id.
    pid_t fore_pgid = tcgetpgrp(0);
    printf("the foregroud pgid is: %d \n", fore_pgid);
    // change the foreground process group id to the redefined child process's group pid.
    tcsetpgrp(0, child_gpid);
    fore_pgid = tcgetpgrp(0);
    printf("the foregroud pgid is: %d \n", fore_pgid);
```

result: the program just stuck on this `tcsetpgrp(0, child_gpid);` line
because it didn't print out some strings after that.

note that, above is only my thought, it might not be correct; I don't know how to only kill my child process, but not the background shell. If you know how to do this, please help me. 
Tons of thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Here is an example from IBM of what they have done

[IBM Example of tcsetpgrp()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/rttcsp.htm)